# Find pairs of consecutive integers in array PYTHON

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop, range

I'm trying to loop through an array and return an integer every time it shows up twice --- I've been trying to figure this out for days and really need some help

example:

```
input = [3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4]
result = [4,6,4]
```

```
result=[]
def findPairs(input):
    i = 0
    while i < len(input):
        for j in input:
            if input[1]==input[2]:
                result.append(j)
                i += 1
    print(result)
        
        
        
print (findPairs(input))
```

Comment: You're only checking `input[1]` and `input[2]`, not `input[i]` and `input[j]`.

Comment: Why is `4` in the result only once, but `6` is two times?

Comment: If you are interest in whether *adjacent* values are equal, then you can loop over pairs of adjacent values `for a, b in zip(input, input[1:]):`. If you are interested in whether a value has been seen *anywhere* before, you can values to a set as you iterate over the list, and test for inclusion in the set.

Comment: The most important thing to learn here is not how to fix this particular bug, but how to debug simple programs. Your test is `if input[1]==input[2]` and you can easily print out the values of `input[1]` and `input[2]` every time you iterate the loop. Do the printed values match what you expected at each iteration? They don't. That's a big clue to what is going on.

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: So, what if you had `[2, 3, 4,4,4,4, 5, 6,6]`? Should the result be `[4,4,4,6]`? Or `[4,4,6]`? or `[4, 6]`?

Comment: Sorry edited result - there was a typo! 

@barmar - yeah I know I'm only checking input[1] against input[2] -- i'm just really new at this and having a hard time getting the inputs to increase on each loop...

Comment: Ok, so basically, you want any contigous run of duplicates collapsed into a single number? So my example abovde, the answer would be `[4, 6]`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  --- if you had [2, 3, 4,4,4,4, 5, 6,6] the result would be [4,4,6]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to the more recent clarifications:

```
def find_pairs(xs):
    result = []
    i = 0
    
    while i < len(xs) - 1:
        if xs[i] == xs[i + 1]:
            result.append(xs[i])
            i += 1
        i += 1

    return result
```

Testing:

```
>>> xs = [3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4]
>>> find_pairs(xs)
[4, 6, 4]
```

---

**Update:** Minor off-by-one bug fix.

Comment: ahhhh this works okay thankyou! I've been looking for a video or something to explain the increasing iteration of an index which you showed me how to do here...but i haven't found one. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: somebody please correct me if I'm wrong but iterating through lists using a while loop, length of the list and an integer as index is not best practice. best practice is to use for loop and get the index number by enumerating the list you are iterating.  check out my new answer for the implementation.

Comment: @RashanArshad often it is better to use a for-loop, but sometimes though, like in this case, the `while` loop is the best solution because each step of the iteration can be controlled. Note, if we find a duplicate, we are supposed to *jump ahead* so as not to double-count pairs. The OP wasn't exactly clear about this.

Comment: aaah okay.  Youre right OP wasn't quite clear I assumed '4,4,4' would return ['4,4']. I should probably delete my answers ...

Comment: @RashanArshad I've already deleted an answer of my own because the OP was so slow in clarifying requirements. It wasn't me who downvoted the question, but it is frustrating when you try to answer an evolving question.

Comment: @alaniwi I'm still not sure fully sure what the OP is asking for.  The solution selected as best answer (this one) returns [4,4,6,4] for input [3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4]

Comment: @RashanArshad See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63238576/find-pairs-of-consecutive-integers-in-array-python/63238716#comment111825222_63238576).

Comment: @RashanArshad   
Hey guys I'm really sorry for the frustration here....this is the first question i've posted on here. I'll work at being more clear in the future. I really appreciate the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this method with list comprehensions -

```
import itertools

inp = [3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4]
l = [i for i in zip(inp, inp[1:]) if i[0]==i[1]] #first get consecutive repeats
out = [k[0] for k, g in itertools.groupby(l)] #sequential grouping of repeated groups to count more than 2 occurances as a single one as well
print(out)
```

```
[4, 6, 4]
```